# Conditionally Replace Elements of an Array Depending on the Contents of Another Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to implement the iRPOP- learning algorithm for neural networks.  I am using numpy for performance reasons. One important optimization requires conditionally zeroing out elements of an float array based on the contents of a boolean array.  The equivalent python code would be:

```
for index, condition in enumerate(boolean_array):
    if condition:
        float_array[index] = 0
```

Is there any way to efficiently do this with numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `float_array[boolean_array] = 0`:

```
In [2]: boolean_array = np.array([True, False, False, True])

In [3]: float_array = np.ones(4) * 1.0

In [4]: float_array
Out[4]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

In [5]: float_array[boolean_array] = 0

In [6]: float_array
Out[6]: array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.])
```